# How to define the application class and the Static variable in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to write the Equivalent code in kotlin, I need to use the static variable defined

```
public class ThisForThatApplication extends Application {

    static ThisForThatApplication appInstance;

    public static ThisForThatApplication getAppInstance() {
        if (appInstance == null) {
            appInstance = new ThisForThatApplication();
        }
        return appInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: use companion block of kotlin

Comment: try using Android Studio `convert to Kotlin` plugin by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K`

Comment: As a side note, you don't instantiate an `Application` by yourself in Android. This is always done by the framework. The correct place to set the `appInstance` field would be the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
class ThisForThatApplication : Application() {

    companion object {

        @JvmField
        var appInstance: ThisForThatApplication? = null



        @JvmStatic fun getAppInstance(): ThisForThatApplication {
            return appInstance as ThisForThatApplication
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appInstance=this;
    }

}
```

For more information please read [**`Static Fields`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields) & [**`Static Methods`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `static` concept in Kotlin. However you can achieve the same using [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). Check out Kotlin [object expression and declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions-and-declarations) for more explanation.

Since in your example you just want to create a Singleton, you can do:

```
class ThisForThatApplication: Application() {
    companion object {
        val instance = ThisForThatApplication()
    }
}
```

However as you're creating Android [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class, would be better in terms of Android to initialize instance in [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) method:

```
class ThisForThatApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: ThisForThatApplication
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ThisForThatApplication.instance = this
    }
}
```

`private set` in the bottom of companion object would allow only ThisForThatApplication class to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

**Application class and Static Variable in Kotlin**

```
class App : Application() {

init {
    instance = this
}

companion object {
    private var instance: App? = null

    fun applicationContext(): Context {
        return instance!!.applicationContext
    }
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
}
}
```

Comment: `return instance!!.applicationContext` -  It will throw NullPointerException if the instance is null.